# What is the shortest path in a binary image that covers all the true valued pixels?

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv, shortest-path

The origin of the problem is that we are given corner points of a polynomial. The points that have integer coordinates which are inside the polynomial are our nodes.

Suppose these nodes are fit onto a boolean matrix such that if a pixel is true, that is inside the polynomial. It means that each pixel corresponds to an integer valued coordinate.

We would like to obtain the shortest path which covers all the `true` pixels (nodes) starting from a given point. This point can be any of the `true` pixels. A node can be revisited. There are only 4 directions, which means the next node must be short of one pixel away vertically or horizontally. The input is probably a big matrix, and the polynomial can be assumed to be a convex one with no holes.

The desired output is a vector of points where the input is a boolean matrix. I need an algorithm that achieves the problem in minimum number of turns.

So far, I have thought of scanning from top to bottom as described:

```
up_or_down = (cur_p.y - top_p.y) < (bot_p.y - cur_p.y)

if (up_or_down)    // up
    while (cur_p.y > top_p.y) {
        if (is_movable(cur_p.up))
            move(cur_p.up)
        else if (is_movable(cur_p.left.up))
            move(cur_p.left)
        else // right is movable
            move(cur_p.right)
    }
else    // down
    ...

while (there_is_movable()) {
    left_or_right = cur_p.x - leftmost_movable_p(cur_p).x < rightmost_movable_p(cur_p).x - cur_p.x

    if (left_or_right) {    // left
        while (leftmost_movable_p(cur_p).x < cur_p.x)
            move(cur_p.left)
        while (rightmost_movable_p(cur_p).x > cur_p.x)
            move(cur_p.right)
        if (up_or_down)    // up, so go down
            if (bot_p.y < cur_p.y)    // check if we reached bottom
                while ( ! is_movable(cur_p.down) )
                    move(cur_p.left)
        else    // down, so go up
            ...
    }

    else {    // right
        ...
    }
}
```

I would like to know if there is a better solution or you think there should be improvements in my algorithm.

Comment: I'm afraid you are asking this question too soon. You have not reached the programming part of the problem.

Comment: @user4581301 You are right. Actually, I am asking for the algorithm. I can handle the programming part. The specification is to improve understanding of the problem.

Comment: @Burak I believe I know the solution, but first I need to ask are you allowed to start at any point? Or do you have to be able to perform the algorithm when starting from every possible point?

Comment: @Alex The starting point can be any point. I will go over your answer by the way.

Comment: @user4581301 Can I ask how should I focus on the problem? I think the problem is clearly stated. I mean can you help me to make the question eligible for an answer?

Comment: @Burak The first suggestion in [ask] is "Search, and research". Research graph algorithms to see if you can find anything similar. Search for implementations others might have posted that could help you. Then make your own attempt and, if you still do not achieve your desired results, then you will be able to post a specific, focused question.

Comment: @beaker Actually I looked at similar post but none of them seemed to be a solution to the specific case of mine. Since the issue here is the algorithm, I felt the need to simply ask it. Maybe that could be made clearer. I will try my best next time.